# Marketing Automation CultureInfo.CurrentCulture problem

Tags: marketing-automation, segmentation

I have marketing automation campaign where I use xconnect segmentation rule **Sitecore.XConnect.Segmentation.Predicates.Interactions.ChannelGroupMatches**.

There are a lot of this error in my Automation Engine log files:

```
[Error] Error during rule evaluation
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Sitecore.Framework.Rules.RuleExecutionException:
 An error occured evaluating the primary condition of the rule.  See the inner exception for details. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Segmentation.Predicates.Interactions.ChannelGroupMatches.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Evaluate>b__0(Interaction interaction)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Rules.BinaryCondition.Evaluate(IRuleExecutionContext context)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Rules.BinaryCondition.Evaluate(IRuleExecutionContext context)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Rules.BinaryCondition.Evaluate(IRuleExecutionContext context)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Rules.BinaryCondition.Evaluate(IRuleExecutionContext context)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Rules.BinaryCondition.Evaluate(IRuleExecutionContext context)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Rules.BinaryCondition.Evaluate(IRuleExecutionContext context)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Rules.BinaryCondition.Evaluate(IRuleExecutionContext context)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Rules.BinaryCondition.Evaluate(IRuleExecutionContext context)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Rules.BinaryCondition.Evaluate(IRuleExecutionContext context)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Rules.BinaryCondition.Evaluate(IRuleExecutionContext context)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Rules.RuleEngine.Run(IRule rule, IFactProvider factProvider)
```

After investigating I found that null reference exception is thrown inside *Sitecore.XConnect.Segmentation.Predicates.dll* on code:

```
    protected ChannelGroup GetChannelGroup(ITaxonomyManagerProvider taxonomyManagerProvider)
    {
      return taxonomyManagerProvider.GetChannelManager().GetChannelGroup(this.ChannelGroupId, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }
```

because of my channels don`t have version in **CurrentCulture=="en-US"** (it works good if I change it with **new CurrentCulture("en")**).

Is there any way to change default current culture for Automation Engine or any idea how to fix it without creation on new language version for items?